# How to fix icedteanp plugin error?

Tags: opensuse, java, browser

I'm using openSUSE 11.3 with "latest updates".
I have installed `vimprobable` and [`uzbl`](http://www.uzbl.org/).

Whenever I start one of those two browsers, I get the error message:

> icedteanp plugin error: Failed to run etc/alternatives/../../bin/java.
>    For more detail rerun "firefox -g" in a terminal window.

---

After some time (about 1 minute), the message disappears by itself (or when I click the "close" button). The browser(s) continue loading and again, this error appears on specific sites.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: So what happens if you start a terminal window and run `firefox -g`? Also, please post the output of `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java /usr/bin/java`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `java` alternative is not configured properly, the webbrowser cannot find the binary.

Update your alternatives:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

This should output only one (with a path) or multiple alternatives to choose from.
If only one, check if the path exists, else select your alternative.

Try again opening a page containing java elements.

Still the same error?

First, find out what provides `java`:

```
rpm -q --whatprovides java
```

If this returns nothing, you have to install `java` first.
Otherwise, check where exactly the binary lies:

```
rpm -ql <package-from-above> | egrep '/bin/java$'
```

This should show the `java` binary.

Now update your alternatives to refer to that binary:

```
update-alternatives --set java <path-from-above>
```

Comment: thank you wag! The problem is totally gone after I installed java-src, dev

Comment: Installing new software can also trigger the `update-alternatives` program like described above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and resolved it by going into YaST Software Manager and deleting the OpenJDK version of Java.

Comment: Deleting or uninstalling?